# proof of continuity in product topology Help please

Tags: general-topology

Here is our function $F$

$$F:\mathcal R^n \times I \to \mathcal R^n$$

where $(x,t)\in \mathcal R^n \times I \to (1-t)x \in \mathcal R^n$

all topologies are usual topology!

Book said that this $F$ is 'clearly!!' continuous.

and I can accept it but I want to know specific proof.

I tried to prove that by using definition of continuity. but I couldn't ):

How can I prove it by definition of continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are continuous.  The standard topology on $I = [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is also the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.  So $F$ is the restriction of a continuous polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n \times I$, so every open pullback to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}^n \times I$.

Comment: Unless the OP is asking for a bare bones epsilon delta proof (which is entirely unnecessary), I don't think there's much more to this answer than the above. (Grats on 1000 rep btw!)

Comment: Thank you for answering!!! (: